# Scrollbar hints color scheme for Android Studio and Intellij

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, user-experience, color-scheme, color-blindness

I'm partially color blind and this causes some usability issues when I'm interacting with software, in this case Android Studio and Intellij. The [Color Themes for Intellij](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) website has helped me a lot for customizing the text editor, but there's still one issue.

The right scrollbar on the text editor shows color coded information about the location of errors, warnings and other context aware information.

It's very difficult for me to differentiate the elements of current color scheme for that bar.

**Is there a way to customize it?**

It seems that changing the Theme of the software doesn't affect said color scheme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check

> **Navigate through Setting --> Editor --> colors & Fonts --> General --> Errors and Warnings--> Error --> check Error Stripe mark (choose color you want) to show color code in right scroll**

[image]

another way that might help you ,

> **Navigate to setting --> appearance --> check Adjust color of red-green deficiency (under theme)**

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking for changing highlight levels, I'm looking for setting those levels as color blind safe.

Comment: i think your problem is solved as you can customize color of error code as shown above.@buzoherbert

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this theme

> https://github.com/oizo/intellij-colorblind-scheme

Also in intelliJ idea, there is an option to enable color-blind mode:

> Settings → Appearance & Behavior → Appearance → Adjust colors for red-green vision deficiency

[image: > http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/09/intellij-idea-15-eap-help-us-test-the-adjustments-for-color-deficiency/]

Comment: Thank you Vojtech. It's bad that Android Studio doesn't come with this customization enabled. Will oizo/intellij-colorblind-scheme work on Android Studio?